# Color of tikz node is not working

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I have the following graph, I aim to have the labels in black color to be orange color. In Overleaf, it's completely normal and the texts are in orange, but when I insert the very same code it shows as the figure below.

[image]

```
\tikzstyle{node_network}=[circle, draw, thin,fill=yellow!50, scale=0.8]
\tikzstyle{node_functional}=[rectangle, draw, thin,fill=orange!70, scale=0.8]
\tikzstyle{node_traffic}=[circle, draw, thin,fill=blue!70, scale=0.8]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick]
    \node[text=orange,scale=0.6] (u_1) at (0.5,2.75) {$u_1$};
    \node[text=orange,scale=0.6] (u_2) at (-0.8,0.5) {$u_2$};
    \node[text=orange,scale=0.6] (u_3) at (1.8,0.5) {$u_3$};
 
    \node[text=orange,scale=0.6] (f1) at (-2.0,2.5) {$f_1$};
    \node[text=orange,scale=0.6] (f2) at (-1.4,1.95) {$f_2$};
    \node[text=orange,scale=0.6] (f3) at (-0.5,0.95) {$f_3$};
     \node[text=orange,scale=0.6] (f4) at (1.25,1.85) {$f_4$};
 % Functional layer nodes
  \foreach \place/\i in 
  {{(-3,2.0)/1},
    {(-0.8,0.75)/2},
    {(1.8,0.75)/3},
    {(0.5,2.5)/4},
    {(3.75,2.0)/5}}
    \node[node_functional] (b\i) at \place {};
    
 % Functional layer links
  \path[thin] (b1) edge (b2);
  \path[thick, orange] (b1) edge (b4) ;
  \path[thick, orange] (b2) edge (b3);
  \path[thin] (b3) edge (b4);
  \path[thick, orange] (b3) edge (b5);
  \path[thin] (b4) edge (b5);
  \path[thick, orange] (b4) edge (b2);
  
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f1) edge (b1);
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f1) edge (b4);
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f2) edge (b2);
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f2) edge (b4);
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f3) edge (b2);
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f3) edge (b3);
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f4) edge (b5);
    \path[thin, dashed, orange!30] (f4) edge (b3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anyone know how to permanently set the text to have a specific color?

Comment: You code is not complete, as the Ti*k*Z style `node_functional` is undefined. Without `node_functional` your text does seem to be in the right color. Could you please added a minimal working example to demonstrate the failure?

Comment: @Jinwen I modified my post to include configuration of ```node_functional```

Comment: The result looks fine to me, all texts are in orange. Are you missing something else?

Comment: @Jinwen yes, that's the issue! It looks fine for me too, but I still get those texts as black not in orange.

Comment: Try to isolate the problematic part from your document, remove the other parts bit by bit while still keeping this issue, then you might be able to locate where is going wrong. If you still can't figure it out, post the complete code replicating the issue in your question so that we can debug it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem, starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}`. Also, not related but `tikzstyle` is deprecated for a long time now, you should use `tikzset` instead and create more styles to avoid redundancies in your code (all the paths options at the end, for example).